Donut with rounded edges in one direction and white border between the segements
Chart js Donut segment is not displayed in one direction. First and last segments are not working as expected 
Expectation : Need chart js donut rounded segments displayed in one direction with white border between the segments

Code
    // Create a custom Doughnut type with rounded segments
    Chart.defaults.RoundedDoughnut = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.doughnut);
    Chart.controllers.RoundedDoughnut = Chart.controllers.doughnut.extend({
      draw: function(ease) {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        var easingDecimal = ease || 1;
        var arcs = this.getMeta().data;
        var borderWidth = 20; // Width of the white border for space between segments
        Chart.helpers.each(arcs, function(arc, i) {
          var vm = arc._view;
          var startAngle = vm.startAngle;
          var endAngle = vm.endAngle;
          var radius = (vm.outerRadius + vm.innerRadius) / 2;
          var thickness = (vm.outerRadius - vm.innerRadius) / 2;
          ctx.save();
          ctx.translate(vm.x, vm.y);
          // Draw each arc segment with a white border to create spacing
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
          ctx.lineWidth = thickness * 2 + borderWidth; // Increase width to add border
          ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF'; // Set border color to white
          ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // Ensure all segments are rounded on both ends
          ctx.stroke();
          // Draw inner colored arc over the white border to make it look like a gap
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
          ctx.lineWidth = thickness * 2;
          ctx.strokeStyle = vm.backgroundColor; // Set segment color
          ctx.stroke();

          ctx.restore();
        });
      }
    });
    // Initialize the chart
    window.onload = function() {
      new Chart(document.getElementById('usersChart'), {
        type: 'RoundedDoughnut',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10], // Adjust data values for even segments
            backgroundColor: [
              '#5da4e7', '#8fbbe7', '#addbf0', '#4b8de7',
              '#4da466', '#8ec486', '#b3dba8', '#63b571'
            ],
            borderWidth: 0
          }]
        },
        options: {
          cutoutPercentage: 70,
          tooltips: {
            enabled: false
          } // Optional: Disable tooltips to prevent hover issues
        }
      });
    };

<canvas id="usersChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>


You should specify the chart.js version you are using, in case it is not
the latest, and it doesn't appear to be, since the code of your
custom controller is not compatible with the latest v4 version of chart.js.
In any case, the problem is conceptual, the idea of circular "deck of
cards" with each card partially covered by the next, can't be implemented
by drawing full cards, since this approach is bound to have one card
fully visible and one card covered at both ends.
An alternative would be to draw half-cards, and this would work, except in
the case when the sizes of the sectors are very small - then the visible
half-sector is too much and sectors will overlap incorrectly.
The best solution seems to actually draw the overlapping part, using
context.fill function, filling half circles, rather than
context.stroke of very thick arcs with rounded ends.
Here's the implementation of that idea, using latest chart.js v4 compatible
controller; it should be easy to adapt it to older versions:


class RoundedDoughnut extends Chart.controllers.doughnut {
    static id = "roundedDoughnut";
    draw(...args) {
        super.draw(...args);

        const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        const arcs = this.getMeta().data;
        const borderWidth = 10;
        const borderColor = 'white';

        if(arcs.length === 0){
            return;
        }

        ctx.save();

        const arc = arcs[0];
        ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(arc.x, arc.y, arc.innerRadius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(arc.x, arc.y, arc.outerRadius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

        for(const arc of arcs){
            const startAngle = arc.startAngle,
                radius = (arc.outerRadius + arc.innerRadius) / 2,
                thickness = (arc.outerRadius - arc.innerRadius) / 2 - borderWidth;
            const x0 = arc.x + radius * Math.cos(startAngle),
                y0 = arc.y + radius * Math.sin(startAngle);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x0, y0, thickness, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = arc.options.backgroundColor;
            ctx.strokeStyle = arc.options.backgroundColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x0, y0, thickness + borderWidth, Math.PI + startAngle, 2*Math.PI + startAngle);
            ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.restore();

    }
}

Chart.registry.controllers.register(RoundedDoughnut)

new Chart(document.getElementById('usersChart'), {
    type: 'roundedDoughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10], // Adjust data values for even segments
            backgroundColor: [
                '#5da4e7', '#8fbbe7', '#addbf0', '#4b8de7',
                '#4da466', '#8ec486', '#b3dba8', '#63b571'
            ],
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },
    options: {
        cutout: "70%",
        layout:{
            padding: 10
        },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            } // Optional: Disable tooltips to prevent hover issues
        }
    }
});
<div style="width:400px; height: 400px">
<canvas id="usersChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



Also in a jsFiddle, with the features positioned at the other ends of the segments ("clockwise"), as requested.

How to reduce the width of each segment ?

@user28142193 Do you mean the radial width? Through cutout option (I see I left cutoutPercentage from the original code, but now it's cutout: "70%" - I changed it now).

Is it possible to display the segments in clockwise direction ?

@user28142193 Yes, just change startAngle with endAngle and add (or subtract - to rotate the half-disk by 180 degrees either way) Math.PI to the final  arc call, the one stroke with borderColor. You can find that code in the fiddle that I posted at the end of the answer. I also simplified the first arc call (also in the code snippet), the one filled and stroke with the sector's backgroundColor, it can be a full circle, so there's no need to start it somewhere precisely, and then the lineTo call is no longer necessary to close the figure.
